# accessing foreign keys in djnago views, id attribute of model class

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

Here are three of my models:

```
    class User(AbstractUser):
        pass

    class Category(models.Model):
        Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Listing(models.Model):
        Title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
        Description = models.TextField()
        StartingBid = models.IntegerField()
        Category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, verbose_name="Categories")
        Image = models.URLField()
        CurrentBid = models.IntegerField()
        Author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        Close = models.BooleanField()
```

Here's the url which takes me to the required view:

```
    path("<str:user>/<str:name>", views.name, name="name"),
```

And finally the name view:

```
def name(request, user, name):
    try:
        l = Listing.objects.get(Title=name)
    except Listing.DoesNotExist:
        l = None
    try:
        **bid = Bid.objects.get(Bidder=user, Item=name)**
    except Bid.DoesNotExist:
        bid = None
    if l.CurrentBid == bid.Value and l.Close:
        won = True
    else:
        won = False
    if l.Author == user:
        owner = True
    else:
        owner = False
    watchlist = Watchlist.objects.all()
    if name in watchlist:
        added = True
    else:
        added = False
    return render(request, "auctions/name.html", {
        "item": l,
        "added": added,
        "form_bid": BidForm(),
        "m": "",
        "owner": owner,
        "comments": Comments.objects.filter(Item=name),
        "won": won
    })
```

This is where the problem is occuring:

```
    bid = Bid.objects.get(Bidder=user, Item=name)
```

The error message:

> Field 'id' expected a number but got 'admin'.(admin is the username)

I figured what the problem is, but i don't know what to do. Bidder attribute of class bid is a Foreign key to the class User

Can someone please tell me how to do it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
path("<str:user>/<str:name>", views.name, name="name")
```

The error tells you "Hey, `Bidder` is supposed to be an int (it's a foreign key), and you gave me a string". I believe you can either give it the `id` or an instance of the model referenced by the ForeignKey. You have the user's username here, so you could do

```
bidder = User.objects.get(username=user)
```

Note that you'll have the same issue with the `Item` argument, as I assume it's a ForeignKey referencing a `Listing` instance? Then you'll need to pass your `l` variable here. In the end:

```
bid = Bid.objects.get(Bidder=bidder, Item=l)  # `bidder` and `l` are instances of `User` and `Listing`
```

It would probably be better to set up your path to use the primary keys here, and use `.get(pk=...)` to fetch the instance of each model:

```
path("<int:user_id>/<int:listing_id>", views.name, name="name")
```